# "SPManager.Initialize failed" when running PSConfig on sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, patch

I am trying to update a sp2013 farm from SP1+July 2016 CU to the August 2020 CU. I've already installed the patch, and am trying to run PSCONFIG now.
The first APP server (which runs Central admin) PSCONFIG command completed successfully, but I have been unable to get any of the remaining servers to complete - I've tried both WFE and another App server, in all cases, PSCONFIG exits with the following error:

```
> PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd install
features -cmd secureresources
SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard version 15.0.4939.1000. Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2012. All rights reserved.

Performing configuration task 1 of 7
Initializing SharePoint Products upgrade...

Waiting to get a lock to upgrade the farm.

Successfully initialized the SharePoint Products configuration.

Performing configuration task 2 of 7
Initiating the upgrade sequence...

Failed to initiate the upgrade sequence.

An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown.

Total number of configuration settings run: 2
Total number of successful configuration settings: 1
Total number of unsuccessful configuration settings: 5
Successfully stopped the configuration of SharePoint Products.
Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.  Configuration must be performed before you use SharePoint Products.  
For further details, see the diagnostic log located at d:\spdata\Logs\ULS\PSCDiagnostics_12_4_2020_16_38_33_727_1311047457.log and the application event log
```

When I check the PSCDiag file, the error is just "Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown"

```
12/04/2020 15:56:42  12  ERR            Task upgradebootstrap has failed with an unknown exception 
12/04/2020 15:56:42  12  ERR            Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.BootStrap(Guid sessionId, SPUpgradeOperationFlags flags)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeBootstrapTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
```

I've rebooted (multiple times)
Tried stopping/restarting IIS
Cleared the sharepoint config cache
Run Get-spProduct -local - it give an error the first time I run it, but then succeeds the second time (which is the same behavior I had on the first server which completed successfully)

```
> Get-SPProduct -Local
Get-SPProduct : Failed to call GetTypes on assembly
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91. Could not load file or assembly
'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-SPProduct -Local
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...letGetSPProduct:
   SpCmdletGetSPProduct) [Get-SPProduct], SPUpgradeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SpCmdletGetSPPro
   duct

> Get-SPProduct -Local

ProductName                    Required   Missing              Servers
-----------                    --------   -------              -------
Microsoft SharePoint Server... True                            {}
Microsoftr Project Server 2013 True                            {}
```

I do see a few UNEXPECTED level errors in the ULS logs relating to Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin

```
ERROR Failed to call GetTypes on assembly Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

and also one that appears related to inability to update the central admin - but I believe that would have been done when I ran PSConfig on the Central admin server, which completed successfully

```
12/04/2020 16:58:20.93 OWSTIMER (0x3254) 0x0B3C SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPUpgradeSession ajxme ERROR CanUpgrade [SPContentDatabase Name=SYSdev_content_CentralAdmin] failed. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

any suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  The central admin server on which PSCONFIG completed successfully had SQL Server 2014 PowerPivot installed, but the other servers in the farm all had SQL Server 2012 PowerPivot installed. (this is dev environment, and PowerPivot had been installed for testing long ago).

I uninstalled SQL Server 2012 PowerPivot and installed SQL Server 2014 PowerPivot on all other servers.  PSCONFIG then completed successfully on all the servers.